# How to print a copy AND a pdf at the same time from any software?

Tags: windows, printing, print-to-pdf

The solution would allow one to generate a .pdf, *and* a paper copy while the software only sends one job to a single printer.
Is it possible to configure Windows print devices to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be possible with Windows on its own, but...

I use PDFCreator 1.7.1 (old version, see note below) in Windows 7. There is *Print after saving* option. You can choose whether to use specific printer or to query a user with additional dialog. This setting may be saved to a profile.

In case you don't need a paper copy sometimes, you can have separate virtual printers associated with different profiles -- one to generate pdf and to print on paper, another to generate pdf only.

Notes:

- I have found the said option, yet I haven't tested it a lot.
- There are newer versions of PDFCreator which may or may not have the option you need. Some time ago *2.x.x* didn't have another option I need, so I stuck to the old version.

[Download location](http://download.pdfforge.org/download/pdfcreator) (older releases [here](http://download.pdfforge.org/download/pdfcreator/list)). This software is free (see [license](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/license)).

Comment: I have tested the following combinations:
- ver. 1.7.3 on Windows XP: OK, as you said; 
- ver. 1.9.4 on Windows 7 x64: KO, option is here but I can't select the printers; 
- ver. 2.3.0 on Windows 7 x64: OK, option is now *Actions -> Print document*

Comment: 1.7.3 seem to be the last version that was not based on .NET, that makes it a good choice for some modest systems. I have selected your post as acceptedanswer because a free solution is a better one ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the latest version 3.5.1 of PDFCreator on Windows 10. 
You can print a copy AND a pdf at the same time by selecting a profile:
"Print after saving".
Please refer to image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**set up a printer to print to multiple devices**

1.Open Printers and Faxes.

2.Right-click the printer you are using, and then click Properties.

3.On the Ports tab, select the Enable printer pooling check box.

4.Click each port where the printers you want to pool are connected.

Comment: Looks like a good solution but unfortunately, according to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958172.aspx), printer pooling does not duplicate jobs, it distributes to a pool of identical printers

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not seem to allow the possibility to do this unfortunately.
If money is not a problem, there is a software that can exactly do the job: [Print Distributor](http://www.frogmorecs.com/).